# ¿Como añado icon con fuentes .ttf en elementos de un menu?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, programación-móvil

Lo que actualmente quiero hacer es meter una fuente .ttf que descargue en la carpeta de assets del proyecto de android de xamarin, pero cada que lo intento me marca error de sintaxis el proyecto.

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu"
                HasUnevenRows="True">
        <d:ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>Acerca de Nosotros</x:String>
                <x:String>Contactanos</x:String> ---- Aqui quiero poner los icons
            </x:Array>
        </d:ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"  d:Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="20"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David, que fuente quieres utilizar, y donde esta el código que te marca error?
La fuente que puedes usar para mostrar Iconos es Segoe 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font#about-segoe-mdl2-assets
y para poder lograr este debes hacer los siguientes pasos:
en tu Archivo App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
 <OnPlatform x:Key="SegMDL2" x:TypeArguments="x:String" Android="SegMDL2.ttf#Segoe MDL2 Assets" iOS="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Luego donde tu quieras llamar a tu fuente:

```
<ButtonImage>
<ButtonImage.Source>
<FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource SegMDL2}" Glyph="&#xE722;"/>
</ButtonImage.Source>

</ButtonImage>
```

Si simplemente quieres usar la fuentes y no colocar iconos

```
<Label Text="Prueba" FontFamily="{StaticResource SegMDL2}"/>
```

puedes aplicar este metodo con la fuente que descargues.